# LINQ sum collection of items to return object with results (multiple columns)

Tags: c#, linq

I know I can do the below with a foreach but was wondering if there is a clean and "sexier" way of doing this with LINQ.

```
public class item
{
    public int total { get; set; }
    public int net { get; set; }
}


class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<item> items = new List<item>()
                               {
                                   new item() { total = 123, net = 423},
                                   new item() { total = 432, net = 54},
                                   new item() { total = 33, net = 57654},
                                   new item() { total = 33, net = 423},
                                   new item() { total = 3344, net = 423},
                                   new item() { total = 123, net = 423},
                                   new item() { total = 123, net = 98},
                                   new item() { total = 123, net = 867},
                                   new item() { total = 123, net = 876},
                                   new item() { total = 123, net = 423},
                                   new item() { total = 123, net = 543},
                                   new item() { total = 543, net = 345},
                               };

        item i = new item();
        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            i.net += item.net;
            i.total += item.total;
        }
    }
}
```

What I would like to do is, for a given list of objects sum each of the columns / fields and return one single object with the sum of each value.

I tried:

```
var result = (from e in items
                     select new
                                {
                                    NET_GRAND = e.net,
                                    TOTAL_GRAND = e.total
                                }).ToList();
```

And variations on the below but with no luck:

```
 var result = (from t in items
                     group t by new {t.net, t.total}
                     into grp
                     select new
                                {
                                    NET_GRAND = grp.Sum(t => t.net),
                                    TOTAL_GRAND = grp.Sum(t => t.total)
                                }).GroupBy(x => new { x.NET_GRAND, x.TOTAL_GRAND }).ToList();
```

**EDIT**

should have pointed out that efficiency is important here as well as sexiness.

Comment: The most efficient solution is the one you already have. Any LINQ-based solution here will be using LINQ just for the sake of using LINQ.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you don't care about iterating the list twice,

```
var i = new item
    { 
        net = items.Sum(it => it.net), 
        total = items.Sum(it => it.total) 
    };
```

If you *do* care about iterating the list twice (as you might be if you were doing this for an `IEnumerable` of unknown origin),

```
var i = items.Aggregate(new item(), 
    (accumulator, it) => 
        new item 
        {
            net = accumulator.net + it.net, 
            total = accumulator.total + it.total 
        } 
);
```

Comment: +1 for the use of `Aggregate` (I just finished writing my own when I saw this posted), though I might suggest using another type for the accumulator to make it explicit what is going on. It's also worth noting to the OP that this is definitely not "sexier" than a simple `foreach` in this particular case.

Comment: agreed on the not so sexy but way more efficient if you have an object with a large number of fields.

Comment: @Jon: In what way is this more efficient than the `foreach`? This does the same thing as the `foreach` but requires an additional intermediate object and delegate invocation. Neither of those is *particularly* punishing from a performance perspective, but they certainly don't make it *more* efficient. I agree, though, that from the answers presented this is the one I'd use.

Comment: @AdamRobinson sorry for the miss understanding I don't think it would be more efficient but more elegant with "LINQYNESS", just didn't want to do multiple linq iterations if avoidable.. or just foreaching

Answer (score 11):

It looks like you really want:

```
var result = new {
    NetGrand = items.Sum(t => t.net),
    TotalGrand = items.Sum(t => t.total)
};
```

On the other hand, I'd probably just separate those into two different local variables:

```
var netGrand = items.Sum(t => t.net);
var totalGrand = items.Sum(t => t.total);
```

Of course this iterates over the list twice, but in most cases I'd expect that not to be noticeable.

Comment: Hi Jon, Will this do an iteration for each variable? i.e. if we have a large object will it become inefficient?

Comment: @Jon: It will iterate over the list twice, yes. But "inefficient" is a relative term - what you're interested in is whether it's fast *enough*.

Comment: In most cases, yes, but this is no more concise than the original `foreach` version. While "fast enough" is a good metric when comparing approaches that differ on other grounds, it seems here like it would be choosing something with clearly poorer performance without gaining anything.

Comment: @AdamRobinson: Will edit with the two-separate-variables version, which *is* more concise :)

Answer (score 2):

```
item totals = new item 
              { 
                 net = items.Sum(i => i.net),
                 total = items.Sum(i => i.total)  
              };
```

But keep in mind that this query will enumerate a list two times, so for a large list this would not so efficient as old good single `foreach` loop.

Comment: +1 for pointing out the (somewhat obvious) fact that this requires two traversals.

Answer (score 1):

```
var item = new item();
item.net = items .Sum(x=>x.net);
item.total = items.Sum(x=>x.total);
```

Comment: Why are you creating a new instance of `item`?

Comment: @Adam Robinson, because OP want's create a new item and fill its property, I don't know why you asked this? Is there any other answer here without creating new instance of item?

Answer (score 0):

Use the foreach loop.   You state that you are concerned about efficiency, and even if you weren't there is no reason to write it using Linq just to be using Linq.

One of the things we discover as we get lots more experience with programs is that just because something is done "the old way" does not make it bad.  And converting to the new-wiz-bang method does not make it better.  In fact, if you have code working the old way, "upgrading" is a cause for injection of defects, with in many cases no advantages.

At best, this Linq method will take 2X longer to compute.

```
var i = new item
    { 
        net = items.Sum(it => it.net), 
        total = items.Sum(it => it.total) 
    };
```

Not sure about the aggregate method, but clearly it will take longer.

Comment: There's no real advantage in using a loop here over `Sum`.  Sum is shorter, more concise, semantically represents exactly the operation that should be performed, performs that operation quite efficiently and without a particularly significant overhead.  It's highly unlikely that the LINQ approach would be anywhere near 2X slower.  They would both be performing an effectively identical overhead.  There would be a touch of overhead for iterating the sequence twice and for the use of a delegate, but both should be rather minimal.

Comment: Would not the TWO linq queries have to iterate over list twice?  Where the foreach (or a for) loop would do it once?  In order to take the same amount of time, the linq would have to iterate twice as fast.  The code for the foreach loop is 1 line of code more - and that line of code is only needed if you want to build up an object with the results.  Otherwise it is using a += in the loop instead of a = items.sum.   BTW:  I use Linq all the time, so I agree that it is a nice and concise way to write code.  My only point is that it is slower.  (I work with high performance code.)

Comment: It *does* do the work twice as fast, and that's because it's doing half as much work.  Which of these code snippets is faster: 1) `foreach(var item in list){Thread.Sleep(1000);Thread.Sleep(1000);}` 2) `foreach(var item in list)Thread.Sleep(1000);foreach(var item in list)Thread.Sleep(1000);`?  One loop that performs two additions per iteration is going to take twice as long as two loops performing one addition per iteration.

Comment: In terms of timing, I expect the getting the next iterator value is the sleep(1000), as a var+= value (with the compiler putting that in a register) is going to take 1 ns. or less actual time, vs calling an iterator to get the next object in a list.  Just wrote a program to test it:  Time using Linq: 0.947901695658294ms
Time using For: 0.496631422516865ms

Comment: timer.Start();
         var i = new Foo()
         {
            val1 = FooList.Sum(it => it.val1),
            val2 = FooList.Sum(it => it.val2)
         };
         timer.Stop();
         Console.WriteLine(@"Time using Linq: {0}ms", timer.DurationMilli);

         timer.Start();
         Foo resultFoo = new Foo();

         foreach (Foo f in FooList)
         {
            resultFoo.val1 += f.val1;
            resultFoo.val2 += f.val2;
         };
         timer.Stop();
         Console.WriteLine(@"Time using For: {0}ms", timer.DurationMilli);

Comment: (Would be nice to be able to format code in comments :-(

Comment: If you change the values to be added to longs, and change the list to an array, you can get Linq to just a 7% slower loop - which is better than I expected.  If you use a List<> and long values it is still 40% slower.

Comment: BTW, I was rounding off when I said best would be 2X, 1.9 is the actual value from my original test.

Comment: LOL got voted down by a "new tech" junkie that doesn't understand high performance systems.  I work with system rated at 1,000,000 concurrent users and can't afford even 7% reduction.  My entire comment was relating to performance, and that is the only thing that I'm addressing here.  I use Linq as well.  Good grief.

Comment: Much of the overhead of LINQ is going to be constant, not scaling with the size of the content.  Sure, querying an in memory list with 10 items could easily take a large *percentage* longer, but the absolutely value of the difference is also entirely negligible, because taking 40% longer to sum the items in a tiny list is still an entirely negligible operation.  Sure, for someone who is actually performing an expensive enough computation to really matter, and for which they've tested thoroughly and found avoiding LINQ to be a noticeable speedup, that's fine.  That just won't happen often.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58454/discussion-between-traderhut-games-and-servy).

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you can accomplish this using LINQ without iterating twice by using GroupBy with a constant value for the key (in this case I use 1).

```
item totals = items.GroupBy(i => 1).Select(g => new item()
{
    net = g.Sum(i => i.net),
    total = g.Sum(i => i.total)
}).Single();
```